# Tomar el Value de Form de Boostrap en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formularios

Es una pregunta sencilla pero que lamentablemente me tiene trabado. Necesito tomar el value de email y de password pero no como hacerlo. No tiene valor input el formulario de boostrap. Al menos no uno que yo pueda ver a simple vista. Entonces no se como capturarlo.

````
    <Form>
    <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formPlaintextEmail">
      <Form.Label column sm="2">
        Email
      </Form.Label>
      <Col sm="10">
        <Form.Control className="email" type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
      </Col>
    </Form.Group>
  
    <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formPlaintextPassword">
      <Form.Label column sm="2">
        Password
      </Form.Label>
      <Col sm="10">
        <Form.Control className="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
      </Col>
    </Form.Group>
  </Form>
    
  <Button className="boton" variant="primary" onClick={validationHandler}>Login</Button>

  </div> ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una buena opción sería convertir los inputs a componentes controlados.

Esto te permitiría guardar sus valores en estados, y cuando llames a la función `validationHandler` podrías acceder a ellos fácilmente.

En otras palabras, deberías crear dos estados:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
```

y luego utilizarlos en los inputs:

```
<Form.Control value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
<Form.Control value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
```